# Can I tighten the laptop hinges to reduce screen wobbling?

Tags: laptop-repair

I want to buy a new laptop, and after an extensive research, I have decided to get an Asus Zenbook 14 (2024). It pretty much satisfies all of my criteria. The only thing that concerns me is that apparently the screen is somewhat wobbly. So I was wondering is it possible to tighten the hinges to fix that? Or is it risky and not worth it? Though I know it probably voids the warranty, but I really like a sturdy screen.

The thing is that I'm currently using a Thinkpad for work, and its build quality has risen the bar for me. If only it had a better battery life, I would get a Thinkpad instead.

Comment: Buy one through some method that allows you to get a full refund if you're not satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the video at
[How to Fix Loose ASUS Zenbook Hinge | Repair Fix Screen Hinge Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAP-NwyE4H4).

The narrator claims that the problem is poor hinges design by ASUS and
shows how to fix it by unscrewing the back and detaching the screen
and tightening the hinges up by applying just the right amount of force.

Frankly, you need for that some tools and some ability in computer repair.
If this isn't so for you, I don't suggest to do it yourself.
Either find a repair-man that can execute it cheaply enough, or decide
on another laptop, or agree to live with it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I saw this video, but I wanted to make sure that it's a reasonable decision, and hear the others' opinion on this. And also since the video is for some years ago, I didn't know if the newer hinges are also like that or not

Comment: That's something you can never know. Even laptops of the same model may differ by parts, manufacturing factory and batch. Just to warn that in case that you break something during the repair, the warranty will most likely not cover the damage. This is why I would advise to buy a laptop that you like, rather than one you need to fix, even if it's costlier (paying for a repairman will also cost).

Comment: FWIW - I use Lenovo ThinkPads. Not everyone can or will. But I have all 4 ThinkPads from 2013 here and all hinges remain tight with 0 play.

Comment: @John Yeah, I know! Their build quality is absolutely exceptional

Comment: Remember this:  Cheaper laptops are not good laptops with margin fat removed. They have cheaper design, cheaper parts and cheaper engineering. These are the reasons they are cheaper and not as good.